# Is there any significance in such Heegner numbers (or class number 1) representation symmetry?

Tags: number-theory, radicals, symmetry, discriminant

$$\mathrm{A003173}(n) = 1+\frac{(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n-1} - (1 - \sqrt{3})^{n-1}}{2\sqrt{3}}$$

for $n = 1,2,3,4$ .

$$\mathrm{A003173}(n) = 19+24\frac{(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n-6} - (1 - \sqrt{3})^{n-6}}{2\sqrt{3}}$$

for $n = 6,7,8,9$ .

In general the recursive form of generalization:

$$\mathrm{A003173}(n) = \mathrm{A003173}(k) + (\mathrm{A003173}(k+1)-\mathrm{A003173}(k))\frac{(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n-k} - (1 - \sqrt{3})^{n-k)}}{2\sqrt{3}}$$

Where $k=1$ for $n = 1,2,3,4$ and $k=6$ for $n = 6,7,8,9$ .

Below is the explicit form of generalization:

$$\mathrm{A003173}(n) = \phi(prime((4\bmod n)!!)) + \left\lfloor n/5 \right\rfloor + ((1 + \left\lfloor n/5 \right\rfloor)^2)!\frac{(1+\sqrt{3})^{n-(1+2\left\lfloor n/5 \right\rfloor)!}-(1-\sqrt{3})^{n-(1+2 \left\lfloor n/5 \right\rfloor)!}}{2\sqrt{3}}$$

For all $n$ except $n=5$ .

In raw Mathematica (WolframAlpha) format the above formula is:

`A003173(n) = eulerphi(prime(mod(4,n)!!))+floor(n/5)+((1+floor(n/5))^2)!*((1+sqrt(3))^(n-(1+2*(floor(n/5)))!)-(1-sqrt(3))^(n-(1+2*(floor(n/5)))!))/(2*sqrt(3))`

Note that all of above covers first four and last four Heegner numbers (eight out of a total of nine) but doesn't cover the middle term: $\mathrm{A003173}(5)= 11$.

Here are other Mathematica expressions for first and last 4 Heegner Numbers

Simplify[Table[1 + ((1 + Sqrt[3])^(n - 1) - (1 - Sqrt[3])^(n - 1))/(2 Sqrt[3]), {n, 1, 4}]]

{1,2,3,7}

Simplify[Table[19 + 24((1 + Sqrt[3])^(n - 6) - (1 - Sqrt[3])^(n - 6))/(2 Sqrt[3]), {n, 6,9 }]]

{19,43,67,163}

Simplify[Table[6*j^2-5 + ((j^2)!)*((1 + Sqrt[3])^(n-1) - (1 - Sqrt[3])^(n-1))/(2*Sqrt[3]), {j,1,2}, {n,1,4}]]

{{1,2,3,7},{19,43,67,163}}

Is there any significance in such Heegner numbers (or class number $1$) representation symmetry?

Comment: I moved my question from mathoverflow to here, since it was not considered to be worthy of attention and appreciation there.

Comment: This is certainly better for MSE, but may I suggest, Alex, that you learn something about formatting mathematics on this site, as your text is barely readable.

Comment: @DietrichBurde - I'm learning formatting in strides - what you could barely read in my question constitutes a huge math formatting progress for me:-) If you would care to improve my bad formatting here - it will help my learning process.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it will help that your questions get more attention.

Comment: What's the meaning of $\phi(prime((4\bmod n)!!))$ ?

Comment: @Aboozar - eulerphi(prime(mod(4,n)!!)

Comment: @Aboozar http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table+prime(mod(4,n)!!)+for+n%3D1...9

Comment: @Aboozar http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table+eulerphi(prime(mod(4,n)!!))+for+n%3D1...9

Comment: That's right . But formulas in line 1,3 and 6 of your question are better than the vague formula on line 8. And i think it's better to ignore (delete) this (and Mathematica format) and ask your question in MO.

Comment: Of course your imagination and creativity for such formula is admirable . But simple thinking is what mathematics (and mathematician!) need.

Comment: @Aboozar - My thinking is that if this generalized explicit formula gives correct values (except for n=5; but the same exception also applies for simpler formulas in lines 1, 3 and 6) it may (or may not) have some underlying reason (unknown to me). Yes, it doesn't look pretty and I wish it would look more compact. I wonder whether or not Occam's razor concept is applicable to mathematics?

Comment: And where is $11$ in all this?

Comment: @ Oscar Lanzi - As have noted already in my question: "Note that all of above covers first four and last four Heegner numbers (eight out of a total of nine) but doesn't cover the middle term: A003173(5)=11A003173(5)=11."